# Subclasses of java.util.Calendar available for commercial use - i.e. IslamicCalendar

Tags: java, internationalization, calendar

I am looking for some subclasses of the *Java* calendar class, preferably a Hijri (Islamic) calendar implementation, but will potentially require more. Does anyone know of a library that is available for commercial use?

I have found IBM's ICU library ([here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime/calendar)), however, they do not extend `java.util.Calendar` and instead have written their own class which also replies on the custom classes; `UDate` and `ULocale`. I am attempting to I18n an existing java application which already has over 400 usages of Calendar so I ideally want to stick to that class. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual with all Date API questions the answer is use [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) if possible, if not, make it possible.

I'd also be wary of IBM Date classes, they produced the current Java date API and while it's a big place, that implementation does not bode well for other offerings.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the icu4j classes inside your own Calendar implementation.

Comment: Thanks - I had considered that but then it involves wrapping date and locale objects as well, as maybe more. Still a possiblity though.