# how could i return an Islamic calendar using java.util.Calendar?

Tags: java, calendar

I knew that java.util.Calendar class method `getInstance()` returns a GregorianCalendar but how could i get an Islamic calendar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subclasses of java.util.Calendar available for commercial use - i.e. IslamicCalendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109346/subclasses-of-java-util-calendar-available-for-commercial-use-i-e-islamiccalen)

Comment: instead of writing duplicate please provide me some suitable answer? How could i find the answer just searching with title?

Comment: I thought my link to Joda Time was a good answer. And the link to the duplicate has some more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's not one built in the API.

You're going to have to subclass the Calendar class to do this or you could look at stuff that people have already written and if that will be suitable for you.

IBM  has one implementation of the [Hijri](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/calendars) calendar.

There's also an [approximate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_islamic.html) one provided by Joda-Time.

Comment: The one provided by JODA is not a subclass of the Calendar class, this would mean that i subclass calendar and then delegate to Joda Chronology to get the calculations done, please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I think the JDK does not ship with an implementation of the Islamic calendar. You'd have to use another library, such as [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_islamic.html).