# How to convert Hijri (Islamic) date to Gregorian date

Tags: java, android, hijri

I want to convert Hijri date to Gregorian date!
I've searched, but unfortunately I found a java class for converting Gregorian to Hijri. I need the opposite.

HijriCalendar.java: 
https://gist.github.com/fatfingers/6492017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_islamic.html) for this.

If you create an Islamic cronology and call withUTC() it should return an UTC cronology which can be converted to whatever is needed.

However, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964663/how-could-i-return-an-islamic-calendar-using-java-util-calendar) post, the joda-Time implementation is only an approximation.

Answer (score 1):

The formula to convert Muslim (M) dates to CE is:

`CE = ((M x 970224)/1000000)+ 621.5774 = CE.nnn`

then `0.nnn x 365` = day of the CE year M year began.

From that you can determine the day you are looking for from the Muslim month chart:

1. Muharram = 30 days;
2. Safar = 29 days;
3. Rabia 1 = 30 days;
4. Rabia 2 = 29 days;
5. Jumada 1 = 30 days;
6. Jumada 2 = 29 days;
7. Rajab = 3 days;
8. Shaban = 29 days;
9. Ramadan = 30 days;
10. Shawwal = 29 days;
11. Zu'lKadah = 30 days;
12. Zu'lhijjah = 29 days (30 days if leap year).

Years run in 30 year cycles.

Each cycle starts on 15 June. The 2nd, 5th, 7th, 10th, 13th, 16th, 18th, 21st, 24th 26th and 29th are leap years.

One cycle = 10, 631 days.

Hope this helps. I also have the formula for converting CE dates to Muslim dates.

Comment: Can you please provide detailed explanation as to what does CE.nnn means. .?